# How to change a shape property using its border in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

How can I use the borders of a shape in JavaFX in order to change one of its properties - height, width, radius, etc.

I've tried doing it using a circle on a circle shape in order to resize the radius, but I was wondering if I can do it using the borders of a shape.

Here it is my custom circle class:

```
public class NewCircle extends Circle {


public NewCircle (double x, double y , double radius, Color colore){
    super(x,y,radius);
    this.setFill(colore);
    this.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler);
    this.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);
    }

double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;

EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseClickedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t ){


    }

};


EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override 
    public void handle(MouseEvent t){
        orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
        orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
        Node source = (Node) t.getSource();
        orgTranslateX = ((Circle) (t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
        orgTranslateY = ((Circle) (t.getSource())).getTranslateY();     
        ((Circle)t.getSource()).toFront();;
    }
};

EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler
= new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {


    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        Node source = (Node) t.getSource();
        Bounds sceneBounds = source.getScene().getRoot().getLayoutBounds();
        Bounds localBounds = source.getBoundsInLocal();

        double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
        double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;

        double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
        double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

        // restirct x movement to scene bounds
        if (offsetX >= 0) {
            if (localBounds.getMaxX() + newTranslateX > sceneBounds.getMaxX()) {
                newTranslateX = sceneBounds.getMaxX() - localBounds.getMaxX();
            }
        } else {
            if (localBounds.getMinX() + newTranslateX < 0) {
                newTranslateX = -localBounds.getMinX();
            }
        }

        // restrict y movement to scene bounds
        if (offsetY >= 0) {
            if (localBounds.getMaxY() + newTranslateY > sceneBounds.getMaxY()) {
                newTranslateY = sceneBounds.getMaxY() - localBounds.getMaxY();
            }
        } else {
            if (localBounds.getMinY() + newTranslateY < 0) {
                newTranslateY = -localBounds.getMinY();
            }
        }
        source.setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
        source.setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
    }
  };

}
```

Comment: Related: [How to resize component with mouse drag in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925612/how-to-resize-component-with-mouse-drag-in-) and [JavaFX rubber band resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547586/java-fx-rubberband-resize-bug)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I've done here is put a couple of shapes on a pane, then allow the user to click on the shapes to select them.  Selecting the shapes surrounds the bounds of the shapes (not the borders) with a bounding box.  The bounding box has anchors on it's corners and side centers.  The user can drag the bounding box to move the selected shape around.  The user can drag the anchors to resize the selected shape.

It's a bit of code because there is a bit of work to do to get it done.  The code could be cleaned up a bit, but it is relatively OK as is.

[image: resize]

*Resizing App*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ResizingSample extends Application {
    private Pane root;
    private Node selectedNode;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(100, 100, 50, 50);
        ellipse.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(200, 250, 100, 100);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.PALEGREEN);

        root = new Pane(
                ellipse,
                rectangle
        );
        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        root,
                        400, 400, Color.ALICEBLUE
                )
        );
        stage.show();

        root.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            final Parent parentNode = ((Node) event.getTarget()).getParent();
            if (selectedNode != null && !(parentNode instanceof ResizingControl)) {
                root.getChildren().removeIf(candidate -> candidate instanceof ResizingControl);
                selectedNode = null;
            }
        });

        makeSelectable(ellipse, rectangle);
    }

    private void makeSelectable(Node... nodes) {
        for (Node node: nodes) {
            node.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                if (selectedNode != node) {
                    root.getChildren().removeIf(candidate -> candidate instanceof ResizingControl);
                    selectedNode = node;

                    node.toFront();
                    ResizingControl resizingControl = new ResizingControl(node);
                    root.getChildren().add(resizingControl);
                }

                event.consume();
            });
        }
    }
}

class ResizingControl extends Group {
    private Node targetNode = null;
    private final Rectangle boundary = new Rectangle();

    private Anchor topLeft = new Anchor(Color.GOLD, true, true, (oldX, oldY, newX, newY) -> {
        double newWidth = boundary.getWidth() - (newX - oldX);
        if (newWidth > 0) {
            boundary.setX(newX);
            boundary.setWidth(newWidth);
        }
        double newHeight = boundary.getHeight() - (newY - oldY);
        if (newHeight > 0) {
            boundary.setY(newY);
            boundary.setHeight(newHeight);
        }

        updateAnchorPositions();
        resizeTargetNode();
    });
    private Anchor topCenter = new Anchor(Color.GOLD, false, true, (oldX, oldY, newX, newY) -> {
        double newHeight = boundary.getHeight() - (newY - oldY);
        if (newHeight > 0) {
            boundary.setY(newY);
            boundary.setHeight(newHeight);
        }

        updateAnchorPositions();
        resizeTargetNode();
    });
    private Anchor topRight = new Anchor(Color.GOLD, true, true, (oldX, oldY, newX, newY) -> {
        double newWidth = boundary.getWidth() + (newX - oldX);
        if (newWidth > 0) {
            boundary.setWidth(newWidth);
        }
        double newHeight = boundary.getHeight() - (newY - oldY);
        if (newHeight > 0) {
            boundary.setY(newY);
            boundary.setHeight(newHeight);
        }

        updateAnchorPositions();
        resizeTargetNode();
    });
    private Anchor rightCenter = new Anchor(Color.GOLD, true, false, (oldX, oldY, newX, newY) -> {
        double newWidth = boundary.getWidth() + (newX - oldX);
        if (newWidth > 0) {
            boundary.setWidth(newWidth);
        }

        updateAnchorPositions();
        resizeTargetNode();
    });
    private Anchor bottomRight = new Anchor(Color.GOLD, true, true, (oldX, oldY, newX, newY) -> {
        double newWidth = boundary.getWidth() + (newX - oldX);
        if (newWidth > 0) {
            boundary.setWidth(newWidth);
        }
        double newHeight = boundary.getHeight() + (newY - oldY);
        if (newHeight > 0) {
            boundary.setHeight(newHeight);
        }

        updateAnchorPositions();
        resizeTargetNode();
    });
    private Anchor bottomCenter = new Anchor(Color.GOLD, false, true, (oldX, oldY, newX, newY) -> {
        double newHeight = boundary.getHeight() + (newY - oldY);
        if (newHeight > 0) {
            boundary.setHeight(newHeight);
        }

        updateAnchorPositions();
        resizeTargetNode();
    });
    private Anchor bottomLeft = new Anchor(Color.GOLD, true, true, (oldX, oldY, newX, newY) -> {
        double newWidth = boundary.getWidth() - (newX - oldX);
        if (newWidth > 0) {
            boundary.setX(newX);
            boundary.setWidth(newWidth);
        }
        double newHeight = boundary.getHeight() + (newY - oldY);
        if (newHeight > 0) {
            boundary.setHeight(newHeight);
        }

        updateAnchorPositions();
        resizeTargetNode();
    });
    private Anchor leftCenter = new Anchor(Color.GOLD, true, false, (oldX, oldY, newX, newY) -> {
        double newWidth = boundary.getWidth() - (newX - oldX);
        if (newWidth > 0) {
            boundary.setX(newX);
            boundary.setWidth(newWidth);
        }

        updateAnchorPositions();
        resizeTargetNode();
    });

    ResizingControl(Node targetNode) {
        this.targetNode = targetNode;

        attachBoundingRectangle(targetNode);
        attachAnchors();

        boundary.toBack();
    }

    private void attachBoundingRectangle(Node node) {
        Bounds bounds = node.getBoundsInParent();

        boundary.setStyle(
                "-fx-stroke: forestgreen; " +
                "-fx-stroke-width: 2px; " +
                "-fx-stroke-dash-array: 12 2 4 2; " +
                "-fx-stroke-dash-offset: 6; " +
                "-fx-stroke-line-cap: butt; " +
                "-fx-fill: rgba(255, 228, 118, .5);"
        );

        boundary.setX(bounds.getMinX());
        boundary.setY(bounds.getMinY());
        boundary.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        boundary.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

        Util.makeDraggable(boundary, (oldX, oldY, newX, newY) -> {
            updateAnchorPositions();

            relocateTargetNode(newX, newY);
        });

        getChildren().add(boundary);
    }

    private void relocateTargetNode(double newX, double newY) {
        if (targetNode instanceof Ellipse) {
            Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse) targetNode;
            ellipse.setCenterX(newX + ellipse.getRadiusX());
            ellipse.setCenterY(newY + ellipse.getRadiusY());
        } else if (targetNode instanceof Rectangle) {
            Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle) targetNode;
            rectangle.setX(newX);
            rectangle.setY(newY);
        }
    }

    private void resizeTargetNode() {
        if (targetNode instanceof Ellipse) {
            Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse) targetNode;
            ellipse.setRadiusX(boundary.getWidth() / 2);
            ellipse.setRadiusY(boundary.getHeight() / 2);

            relocateTargetNode(boundary.getX(), boundary.getY());
        } else if (targetNode instanceof Rectangle) {
            Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle) targetNode;
            rectangle.setWidth(boundary.getWidth());
            rectangle.setHeight(boundary.getHeight());

            relocateTargetNode(boundary.getX(), boundary.getY());
        }
    }

    private void attachAnchors() {
        updateAnchorPositions();

        getChildren().addAll(
                topLeft,
                topCenter,
                topRight,
                rightCenter,
                bottomRight,
                bottomCenter,
                bottomLeft,
                leftCenter
        );
    }

    private void updateAnchorPositions() {
        topLeft.setCenterX(boundary.getX());
        topLeft.setCenterY(boundary.getY());
        topCenter.setCenterX(boundary.getX() + boundary.getWidth() / 2);
        topCenter.setCenterY(boundary.getY());
        topRight.setCenterX(boundary.getX() + boundary.getWidth());
        topRight.setCenterY(boundary.getY());
        rightCenter.setCenterX(boundary.getX() + boundary.getWidth());
        rightCenter.setCenterY(boundary.getY() + boundary.getHeight() / 2);
        bottomRight.setCenterX(boundary.getX() + boundary.getWidth());
        bottomRight.setCenterY(boundary.getY() + boundary.getHeight());
        bottomCenter.setCenterX(boundary.getX() + boundary.getWidth() / 2);
        bottomCenter.setCenterY(boundary.getY() + boundary.getHeight());
        bottomLeft.setCenterX(boundary.getX());
        bottomLeft.setCenterY(boundary.getY() + boundary.getHeight());
        leftCenter.setCenterX(boundary.getX());
        leftCenter.setCenterY(boundary.getY() + boundary.getHeight() / 2);
    }
}

interface DragHandler {
    void handle(double oldX, double oldY, double newX, double newY);
}

// a draggable anchor displayed around a point.
class Anchor extends Circle {
    Anchor(Color color, boolean canDragX, boolean canDragY, DragHandler dragHandler) {
        super(0, 0, 5);
        setFill(color.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        setStroke(color);
        setStrokeWidth(2);
        setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);

        Util.enableDrag(this, canDragX, canDragY, dragHandler);
    }
}

class Util {
    // make a targetNode movable by dragging it around with the mouse.
    static void enableDrag(Circle node, boolean canDragX, boolean canDragY, DragHandler dragHandler) {
        final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
        node.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
            // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
            dragDelta.x = node.getCenterX() - mouseEvent.getX();
            dragDelta.y = node.getCenterY() - mouseEvent.getY();
            node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        });
        node.setOnMouseReleased(mouseEvent -> {
            node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        });
        node.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
            double oldX = node.getCenterX();
            double oldY = node.getCenterY();

            double newX = mouseEvent.getX() + dragDelta.x;
            if (canDragX && newX > 0 && newX < node.getScene().getWidth()) {
                node.setCenterX(newX);
            }

            double newY = mouseEvent.getY() + dragDelta.y;
            if (canDragY && newY > 0 && newY < node.getScene().getHeight()) {
                node.setCenterY(newY);
            }

            newX = node.getCenterX();
            newY = node.getCenterY();

            if (dragHandler != null && (newX != oldX || newY != oldY)) {
                dragHandler.handle(oldX, oldY, newX, newY);
            }
        });
        node.setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> {
            if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            }
        });
        node.setOnMouseExited(mouseEvent -> {
            if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            }
        });
    }

    // make a targetNode movable by dragging it around with the mouse.
    static void makeDraggable(Rectangle node, DragHandler dragHandler) {
        final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();

        node.setOnMouseEntered(me -> {
            if (!me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            }
        });
        node.setOnMouseExited(me -> {
            if (!me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            }
        });
        node.setOnMousePressed(me -> {
            if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            }
            dragDelta.x = me.getX() - node.getX();
            dragDelta.y = me.getY() - node.getY();
            node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        });
        node.setOnMouseReleased(me -> {
            if (!me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                node.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            }
        });
        node.setOnMouseDragged(me -> {
            double oldX = node.getX();
            double oldY = node.getY();

            node.setX(me.getX() - dragDelta.x);
            node.setY(me.getY() - dragDelta.y);

            double newX = node.getX();
            double newY = node.getY();

            if (dragHandler != null && (newX != oldX || newY != oldY)) {
                dragHandler.handle(oldX, oldY, newX, newY);
            }
        });
    }

    // records relative x and y co-ordinates.
    private static class Delta {
        double x, y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I only reply now, thanks a lot for help :) Can I ask another question? I was trying to limit the movement of the figure to the edges of the scene with the same code above, but the movement to the right and down did not work as it should. Where am I wrong?

Comment: It looks like the shape makes a big "jump" to the scene width.